# How to avoid asking password when logging via SSH Key?

Tags: ssh, authentication, ssh-keys, public-key, private-key

I have this scenario:

I login to dns1 with key and same with dns2. Suddenly for each of the keys I used it started to ask me server password, this was never happening in past, and I did no changes on both servers at once to have this occur. I tried to setup a new key in place did not helped. here is the SSH debug log from both servers:

[Server 1 DEBUG -vvv options](https://gist.github.com/highacid/9e7131184244543c729a06de66289001)

[Server 2 DEBUG -vvv options](https://gist.github.com/highacid/e4229de586d33ac9a5fa1ff055f4bc79)

This is quite annoying and no clue why it happened at once. I am using OS X if does make any difference, yet keys are same overall...

Comment: The servers did not accept the key you used. Check the logs on the server to find out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server didn't accept the key your client provided. The client provided only "/Users/kosmos/.ssh/id_rsa_old", guessing that's not the key that's in your authorized_keys file on the remote server.

Check the auth.log on the server, it should contain something helpful as to why. If the public key for that id_rsa_old is in your authorized_keys file on that server, it's probably refusing it because the permissions on authorized_keys are excessively permissive. Make it 600 or 644.

Comment: This is the only LOG I get to: https://gist.github.com/highacid/a33fc75e0733d5e3c29e3c8268455eb2

Comment: that seems to indicate the key you're providing isn't in your authorized_keys file, or that key auth is disabled in sshd_config.